# POST for Edit with model in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller

```
    // GET: /Winches/Edit/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        WinchesBrand winchesbrand = await db.WinchesBrands.FindAsync(id);

        var model = new WinchModel
        {
            WinchBrandId = winchesbrand.WinchBrandId,
            WinchBrandName = winchesbrand.WinchBrandName,
            RopeList = new List<int?>() { }
        };

        foreach (var rope in winchesbrand.Ropes)
        {
            model.RopeList.Add(rope.RopeId);
        }
        if (model.RopeList.Any() == false)
        {
            model.RopeList.Add(null);
        }
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ViewBag.RopeList = db.Ropes.Where(e => e.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

sorry for my English, 
I don't know, how to write Post for this Edit

It is my variant:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(WinchModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<Rope> ropesList = new List<Rope>();
            WinchesBrand winch = new WinchesBrand 
            {
                WinchBrandName = model.WinchBrandName,
                Ropes = ropesList

            };
            //db.WinchesBrands.Where(w => w.WinchBrandName == model.WinchBrandName)
            //    .Update();

            foreach (var ropeId in model.RopeList.Where(w => w > 0))
            {
                db.Ropes.Find(ropeId).WinchesBrand = winch;
            }

            if (model.RopeList.Any() == false)
            {
                model.RopeList.Add(null);
            }
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.RopeList = new SelectList(db.Ropes.Where(e => e.IsDeleted == false), "RopeId", "RopeName");
        return View(model);
    }
```

but this don't refresh(I don't know command for this)

```
{db.WinchesBrands.Where(w => w.WinchBrandName == model.WinchBrandName)
            //    .Update();}
```

P.C. I just started to learn this

Answer (score 0):

Add this before saving changes

```
db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

It will mark your entry as modified and EF will update it.

Comment: The entity type WinchModel is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: Did you update model classes after creating database? did you perform migrations and is there a table containing WinchModel in your database?

Comment: I updated model classes, and didn't perform any migrations. And there is table for WinchModel in my database.

Comment: well, try to perform migration and update database. Your exception 'The entity type WinchModel is not part of the model for the current context.' means that EF have connected to database, but didn't find any table related to model, on what you want perform edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            WinchesBrand winch = new WinchesBrand
            {
                WinchBrandId = model.WinchBrandId.Value,
                WinchBrandName = model.WinchBrandName
            };
            db.Entry(winch).State = EntityState.Modified;

            var ropeToDelete = db.Ropes
                .Where(r => r.IdWinch == model.WinchBrandId 
                    && !model.RopeList.Contains(r.RopeId))
                    .ToList();
            foreach(var rope in ropeToDelete){
                rope.IdWinch = null;
            }

            foreach (var ropeId in model.RopeList.Where(w => w > 0))
            {
                var rope = new Rope { RopeId = ropeId.Value };
                db.Ropes.Attach(rope);
                rope.IdWinch = winch.WinchBrandId;
            }

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

this is correct